# AngularJS concat filter issue with ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-filters

I have a filter which concatenates arrays of objects into a single array of objects. It works on objects set up in the controller but is not working in my view.

My filter:

```
angular.module('hcApp')
.filter('combine', function() {
  return function(items) {
     return [].concat.apply([],items);
  };
});
```

Here is an example filter being used successfully:
Controller:

```
$scope.obj =[ 
[{"day":"10","title":"day","summary":"summary","description":"ok","_id":"53f25185bffedb83d8348b22"}],
[{"day":"3","title":"day","summary":"summary","description":"ok","_id":"53f25185bffedb83d8348b22"}]];
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="event in obj"> 
  <p>{{event}}</p>
</div>
```

Executed logic:

```
[{"day":"3","title":"day","summary":"summary","description":"ok","_id":"53f25185bffedb83d8348b22"}
{"day":"10","title":"day","summary":"summary","description":"ok","_id":"53f25185bffedb83d8348b22"}]
```

With my actual data I am filtering a complex JSON object with the following code in my view:

```
<div class="calDynamic" data-ng-repeat="n in [] | range:100">
<div ng-repeat="cal in calendar[n].year | filterKey:month">
 <p>{{cal}}</p>
<div ng-repeat="items in cal ">    
        <a href="/events/{{items.day}}">
          <article class="eventslist">
           <div class="numberedDate">
               <h3>{{items.day}}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="calInfo">
              <h5>{{items.title}}</h5>
               <p>{{items.summary}}&nbsp;<a>more</a></p>
            </div>
           </article>                
      </div>
</div>
</div>
```

{{cal}} is returning data formatted the same as the data in the $scope.obj but when I add the filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="cal in calendar[n].year | filterKey:month | combine">
```

{{cal}} returns blank instead of returning the restructured array. Is there a problem with my set up or filter? It seems like it should work.

Comment: the "filterKey:month" will be applied to the items before the "combine "filter , if zero items returned after applying the "filterKey:month" , then it will be blank.

Comment: It occurs when there are multiple rows of items returned after "filterKey:month"

Comment: Probably you should keep a console log in `combine` filter to see what exactly it is getting